# More gentle way to hook Wordpress custom url

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, php, functions

I have written a plugin named `foo`, and I want when user typed url `/hello` and it will display the string `world`

There is [an existing post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4365145/wordpress-plugin-hook-on-custom-url) which uses the following code

```
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] == '/hello') {
  echo "world";
  die;
}
```

But this is hacky, as it terminates immediately. For example, it ignores the [`shutdown`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/shutdown) hook.

Are there any better approach allow me to print the output and follow the action lifecycle gracefully?

Comment: Is the aim to use a template, for instance, to display content ('world') - but without completely by-passing WordPress or aborting it early? The linked post is to do with ajax - if so have you look at the proper way of handling ajax actions through WordPress?

Comment: @StephenHarris, I want to display the output no matter what template is used by the users.

Comment: You want to display it where? 'where' has a lot to do with which hook you use.

Comment: @Howard - I understand that. Could you explain what exactly you're trying to achieve? As the best answer will depend on that. My initial suggestion was to force WP to use a template you provide, which contains nothing but the content.

Comment: @StephenHarris, for example, I need to generate a virtual `sitemap.xml` without an actual file being written in the local file system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it seems you want to leave it as a late as possible before setting what WordPress should return (in certain circumstances - e.g. when `sitemap.xml` is being requested).

There are two methods  - which are broadly identical - but using the WordPress API do varying degrees.

The same principal applies to almost any content format (JSON, ICAL etc) and not just XML

#### Method 1: Add a feed:

Benefits of this is that WordPress immediately 'recognizes' the request. Unfortunately, it leaves you with 'feed' in the url - which you may/may not be desirable. For ICAL calendars, for instance, I think this method works well;

```
add_action('init','eventorganiser_public_export');
function eventorganiser_public_export(){
    add_feed('wpse73174', 'wpse73174_content_callback');    
}
```

Then the output is determined by `wpse73174_content_callback()` and is available at `www.example.com/feed/wpse73174/` (depending on permalinks).

### Method 2: Manual approach

A bit more 'hands on' is to use to `redirect_template` action. It's up to you here to decide if the query is for the content you are about to serve:

```
add_action('template_redirect','maybe_wpse73174_content_callback');
function maybe_wpse73174_content_callback(){
   if( /* we are after this content */ ){
         wpse73174_content_callback();
   }
}
```

The problem here is now deciding whether the user is requesting your content. You'll need to add your own rewrite rules / permastructures and query variables to recognize the query. (For JSON content its quite nice to add an endpoint). You might find these [articles written by me at WP.Tuts](http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/creative-coding/the-rewrite-api-the-basics/) relevant.

### The callback

The callback function `wpse73174_content_callback()` is require to set the headers (if appropriate), print the content and then `exit()`;

```
function wpse73174_content_callback(){
  echo 'Hello World';
  exit();
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. You 2nd approach seems is what I need, but as it require a hard `exit`, so `shutdown` hook cannot be called. Of course, this might be the wordpress design fault and is a know limitation.

Comment: Strictly speaking it isn't necessary. But in the 2nd WordPress will try to load a template. One way would be to hook late onto `template_include` and return false if you are producing the output. But that assumes WP hasn't interpreted the query feed. Source: https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/3.4.2/wp-includes/template-loader.php

Comment: In the 2nd method, as far as I'm aware, you are only missing out on the `shutdown` hook.